# import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder results in error compiled in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

For this two imports;

```
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
```

I got this error:

```
Access restriction: The type BASE64Decoder is not accessible due to restriction on required library C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

That error is caused by your Eclipse configuration. You can reduce it to a warning. [Better still](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html), use a Base64 encoder that isn't part of a non-public API. Apache Commons has [one](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html), or when you're already on Java 1.8, then use [`java.util.Base64`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html).

Comment: I guess it was downvoted in favor of nIKUNJ or Jon Skeeter answers.

Comment: @VladimirZhilyaev That's not what the downvote system is for. It is expressly for 'this answer is not useful'. If there's a better answer it should certainly be upvoted, but downvotes should be applied to incorrect or irrelevant answers. It's clear that some people have other agendas.

Comment: Also note that this particular import only works with Oracle JVMs. Other vendors will most likely not have this class causing your program to break.

Comment: @EJP Changing to warning solves the problem but will work without any problem in future like will it compile and build normally.

Comment: To update config:  Window->Perferences->Java->Compiler->Errors/Warnings->Deprecated and restricted API->Forbidden reference  (set to "Warning" instead of "Error"

Comment: In Java 8 you don't need to use an external base 64 codec anymore, so I've [added an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28628476/589259) that includes a code fragment and reasoning why internal classes should not be used. Java 7 is almost end of support now.

Comment: There is no valid reason for the downvote. @EJP  stated the cause:" caused by your Eclipse configuration.", Solution 1:"You can reduce it to a warning", Solution 2:"use Apache Commons"  ....stop the random downvoting it sucks.

Comment: @Ali786 I cannot predict the future. Strange question.

Answer (score 129):

Go to Window-->Preferences-->Java-->Compiler-->Error/Warnings.
Select **Deprecated and Restricted API**. Change it to **warning.**
Change **forbidden** and **Discouraged** Reference and change it to warning. (or as your need.)

Comment: Same problem occurs when trying to use sun.misc.Signal these days as well. Answering the actual question solved my issue as well.

Comment: It may have "answered the question" but masking an error as a warning is a poor solution (_though not bad enough to downvote_).  [@Orism](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12090601/573057)'s answer below using `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter` **solves the problem** without additional dependencies where JDK >= 1.6

Comment: @earcam It's only an error because of an over-enthusastic Eclipse default configuration. The Java compiler doesn't consider it an error and neither does NetBeans.

Comment: @EJP agreed - an error is fatal is and this certainly shouldn't be, but as per Jon Skeet's answer - it's a valid and serious warning of runtime portability. Anyway think this is largely historical now (2011==Indigo), in Kepler the default is warning (not sure since which version).

Answer (score 38):

Sure - just don't use the Sun base64 encoder/decoder. There are plenty of other options available, including [Apache Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) or this [public domain implementation](http://www.iharder.net/current/java/base64/).

Then read [why you shouldn't use sun.* packages](http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/faq/faq-sun-packages.html).

Comment: Since oracle wanted everything to be oracle branded when taking over Sun, this would have been a perfect opportunity to repackage everything and get rid of this class once and for all!

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen They did something better; they [added a Base64 class into `java.util`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28628476/589259).

Answer (score 24):

Java 6 ships the `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter`. This class provides two static methods that support the same decoding & encoding:

`parseBase64Binary() / printBase64Binary()`

**Update:**
Since Java 8 we now have a much better [Base64](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) Support.

Use this and you will not need an extra library, like `Apache Commons Codec`.

Comment: Personally I don't really like that API and I would not use base 64 from an XML related class (it binds your code to an XML component that may otherwise not be required). But Oracle finally decided to implement base 64 [in the Util package in Java 8](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28628476/589259), so it's not required anymore.

Answer (score 8):

This error is because of you are importing below two classes
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder; import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;. Maybe you are using encode and decode of that library like below.

```
new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
newBASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedData);
```

Yeah instead of sun.misc.BASE64Encoder you can import
 `java.util.Base64` class.Now change the previous encode method as below:

```
encryptedData=Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedByteArray);
```

Now change the previous decode method as below

```
byte[] base64DecodedData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64EncodedData);
```

Now everything is done , you can save your program and run. It will run without showing any error.

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem on jdk1.6.0_37.
This is the only JDE/JRE on my system. I don't know why, but the following solved the problem:

> Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path - > Libraries
>
> Switch radio button from **Execution environment** to **Alernate JRE**. 
>   This selects the same jdk1.6.0_37, but after clean/build the compile error disappeared.

Maybe clarification in answer from  *ram* (Mar 16 at 9:00) has to do something with that.

Comment: This works because an Execution environment only exposes the Java standard API while selecting the JDK exposes all public classes, including the ones *you should not use*.

Answer (score 5):

Yup, and sun.misc.BASE64Decoder is way slower: 9x slower than java.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary() and 4x slower than org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(), at least for a small string on Java 6 OSX.

Below is the test program I used. With Java 1.6.0_43 on OSX:

```
john:password = am9objpwYXNzd29yZA==
javax.xml took 373: john:password
apache took    612: john:password
sun took       2215: john:password
```

Btw that's with commons-codec 1.4. With 1.7 it seems to get slower:

```
javax.xml took 377: john:password
apache took    1681: john:password
sun took       2197: john:password
```

Didn't test Java 7 or other OS.

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestBase64 {
    private static volatile String save = null;
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        String teststr = "john:password";
        String b64 = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(teststr.getBytes());
        System.out.println(teststr + " = " + b64);
        try {
            final int COUNT = 1000000;
            long start;
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i=0; i<COUNT; ++i) {
                save = new String(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(b64));
            }
            System.out.println("javax.xml took "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-start)+": "+save);
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i=0; i<COUNT; ++i) {
                save = new String(Base64.decodeBase64(b64));
            }
            System.out.println("apache took    "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-start)+": "+save);
            sun.misc.BASE64Decoder dec = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder();
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i=0; i<COUNT; ++i) {
                save = new String(dec.decodeBuffer(b64));
            }
            System.out.println("sun took       "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-start)+": "+save);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be useful to document the source of speed claims like that.

Comment: I think you mean javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter; Please correct me if I'm wrong however seeing as you gave this as an answer rather than a comment I doubt you will.

Comment: Sure, avgvstvs, test program and environment details added.

Comment: Thank you for performing this analysis, but it really doesn't answer the question. You could consider creating a separate self answered question.

Comment: fwiw i reran this test with java 8 and the new standard java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode("b64") is a now little faster than the previous winner, javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.

Comment: sorry! java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(b64) is a little slower than  javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter. But apache codec 1.10 is ~10x slower.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the Build Path settings in the project properties.
2. Remove the JRE System Library
3. Add it back; Select "Add Library" and select the JRE System Library. The default worked for me.

This works because you have multiple classes in different jar files. Removing and re-adding the jre lib will make the right classes be first. If you want a fundamental solution make sure you exclude the jar files with the same classes.

Answer (score 2):

This error (or warning in later versions) occurs because you are compiling against a Java Execution Environment. This shows up as `JRE System library [CDC-1.0/Foundation-1.0]` in the Build path of your Eclipse Java project. Such environments only expose the Java standard API instead of all the classes within the runtime. This means that the classes used to *implement* the Java standard API are not exposed.

You can allow access to these particular classes using access rules, you could configure Eclipse to use the JDK directly or you could disable the error. You would however be hiding a serious error as [Sun internal classes shouldn't be used](http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/faq/faq-sun-packages.html) (see below for a short explanation).

---

Java contains a [`Base64` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) in the standard API since Java 1.8. See below for an example how to use it:

Java 8 import statement:

```
import java.util.Base64;
```

Java 8 example code:

```
// create a byte array containing data (test)
byte[] binaryData = new byte[] { 0x64, 0x61, 0x74, 0x61 };
// create and configure encoder (using method chaining) 
Base64.Encoder base64Encoder = Base64.getEncoder().withoutPadding();
// encode to string (instead of a byte array containing ASCII)
String base64EncodedData = base64Encoder.encodeToString(binaryData);

// decode using a single statement (no reuse of decoder)
// NOTE the decoder won't fail because the padding is missing
byte[] base64DecodedData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64EncodedData);
```

---

If Java 8 is not available a library such as [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) or [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/BaseEncoding.html) should be used.

---

[Sun internal classes shouldn't be used](http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/faq/faq-sun-packages.html). Those classes are used to *implement* Java. They have got public methods to allow instantiation from other packages. A good build environment however *should* protect you from using them.

Using internal classes may break compatibility with future Java SE runtimes; the implementation and location of these classes can change at any time. It should be strongly discouraged to disable the error or warning (but the disabling of the error is suggested in previous answers, including the two top voted ones).

Answer (score 2):

Be careful, `sun.misc.BASE64Decoder` is not available in JDK-13

Comment: This could be a problem.. because i need to use BASE64Decoder (to give support to java 6 or 7) and when clients upgrade to more recent versions of JAVA, it will break the code...

Answer (score 2):

Was getting `sun.misc.base64encoder cannot be resolved to a type` on eclipse -

1. Resolved this by pointing eclipse to use Java version 1.8 installed on system -
   Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs -> add jre path (eg: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271)
2. Right-click on project -> Maven -> Update project

This will resolve then.

Comment: thank you, you really save my days, I'm new in java and got error in library used

Answer (score 1):

I am using unix system.

In eclipse project-> Properties -> Java Compiler -> Errors/Warning -> Forbidden Access(access rule) -> Turn it to warning/Ignore(Previously it was set to Error).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very Old post. Since we don't have any thing sun.misc in maven 
we can easily use

StringUtils.newStringUtf8(Base64.encodeBase64(encVal));
From org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

Answer (score 0):

solution: go into java 8 sdk fodler, from jre\lib\rt.jar copy to sdklib.jar (it is somewhere in eclipse folder) classes (with same paths):

> sun/misc/BASE64Decoder.class,
> sun/misc/BASE64Encoder.class,
> sun/misc/CharacterDecoder.class,
> sun/misc/CharacterEncoder.class

that's all

Answer (score -1):

Add base64decoder jar and try these imports:

```
import Decoder.BASE64Decoder;
import Decoder.BASE64Encoder;
```