# How to get the JAR file for sun.misc.BASE64Encoder class?

Tags: java, android, jar, base64

I have some code in my Activity class that uses `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder` class. But it is showing `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : sun.misc.BASE64Encoder`. Do I need the `jar`? Where can I download it from?

Comment: Don't use non-public API. Read this thread for more details.


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549464/import-sun-misc-base64encoder-got-error-in-eclipse/5549512#5549512

Comment: I'am new to android. Could you please explain me where i'am wrong? How can i encrypt my string using that class?

Comment: Encryption is not encoding. To do the encoding, you can use the BASE64.The base64 maps 6-bit blocks of binary data into 64 different character representations.

Comment: okay. but i have to encrypt my data. How can i encrypt ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `sun.*` classes. For Base64 in Android, use its [native class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) or add a library to your project that does this (Apache commons, etc.). Alternatively just copy the Android source code to your project (in your own package), if you need to use it on pre-2.2 devices.

Comment: I am using java-8-241 and rt.jar contains Base64Encoder and Base64Decoder, but the openjdk only have Base64, and Base64 was find in both jres. So, is better using Base64 with java-8

Comment: you don't always have a choice

Answer (score 4):

Since **Java 8** you can use [`java.util.Base64`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) class:

```java
byte[] original = "Base64".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

// encode
byte[] toBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encode(original);

// decode
byte[] fromBase64 = Base64.getDecoder().decode(toBase64);

// output
System.out.println(new String(toBase64)); //QmFzZTY0
System.out.println(new String(fromBase64)); //Base64
System.out.println(Arrays.equals(original, fromBase64)); //true
```

---

<sup>See also: [How can I convert a string into a GZIP Base64 string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66409602/14940971)</sup>

Comment: I am using java-8-241 and rt.jar contains Base64Encoder and Base64Decoder, but the openjdk only have Base64, and Base64 was find in both jres. So, is better using Base64 with java-8.

Answer (score 2):

1. Just add rt.jar to the build path of the project from path 
   `C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.202.08\jre\lib`
2. Copy the jar and paste in the libraries folder of the project.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. It **puts off** solving the problem. The real solution is to fix your code so that it doesn't use the internal class ... that it should never have been using in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

For me it is resolved with simple steps, I was using Java11 JDK.As, in this version Base64 classes are deprecated, we are getting this issue. Changing to Java 8 solved the issue.
Steps: In Eclipse,

1. Go to, Windows-> Preferences-> Installed JREs
2. Add-> select JDK8 or lesser version of JDK->Add
3. Make it as default JDK by selecting this JDK
4. Apply and Close

And, Done.

Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem.  It **puts off** solving the problem.  The real solution is to fix your code so that it doesn't use the internal class ... that it should never have been using in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

It's available in rt.jar, that comes with Sun java runtimes.

In 1.5.0_06 : jre\lib\rt.jar

Comment: Yea ... but Java 1.5 is about 20 years out of date.  In fact, this particular class was **dropped** in Java 9, and (AFAIK) has never been present on the Android platform, which is what this question was about.