# trying to compile ehcache - javax.transaction package not found

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

I want to use the ehCache as 2nd level cache in my application.
I downloaded the latest version from the ehcache web site. Unfortunatly no jar file is provided, therefor I wanted to compile the code myself. I put it into a new Eclipse dynamic Web Project and added the necessary jars that came with the download to the Build Path. But now, there are still errors in my project..

e.g. this fails: import javax.transaction.TransactionManager;

Does anybody know why? Usually I have javax package available in a Eclipse Web project...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow have not gotten the original javax package.

I answer my own question because an other reference was missing after adding the javaee package. This was the one to the `sun. misc.Unsafe`.
It does not have to be downloaded, but to be able to use it, the compiler settings have to be changed in Eclipse as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5549580/1737854