# NEW is internal proprietary API

Tags: java, compiler-warnings

During build of our project we get a rather unexplained warning:

```
    [javac] (...)\SessionKeeper.java:39: warning: NEW is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
    [javac]     private static final int timeOfInactivity = 1000 * 60 * 9; // allowed time of inactivity
    [javac]                                ^
```

Additional info:

- Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.4 compiled on May 22 2012
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b16)

Can anyone explain why the compiler makes this warning, and what I should change to avoid it?

[Edit] Added nearby code

```
private static final String CLASS_NAME = SessionKeeper.class.getName();

    private static final int logoutDelaySeconds = 1000 * 60; // logout after 1 min. from the point when dialog was shown to the user
    private static final int timeOfInactivity = 1000 * 60 * 9; // allowed time of inactivity

    private boolean isSchedulerStarted = false; // indicates if SessionKeeper was started or not

    private static SessionKeeper instance;
```

[edit] Since quite a few requested the source I attached it here (expires in 24h):
http://pastebin.com/t2M5mgd0

[edit] What have been tried so far:

- Inlining the constant -> error goes to the line above
- Reactoring SessionKeeper to not extend any class -> same error
- Removing CLASS_NAME and logging statements

Comment: Please show us the relevant code from SessionKeeper.java

Comment: Have you mistakenly written the new operator in uppercase, and it somehow auto imported a class like com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.NEW ?

Comment: @supersam654 I can attach a few lines before and after to the question.

Comment: @Luciano. there is a 15 instance of "new" in the file, but grepping it for "NEW" return no results.

Comment: And what imports do you have in that file?

Comment: @Albatros What is on line 39 of SessionKeeper.java?

Comment: @Albatros Which line is 39? Is the file getting changed or modified during compilation?

Comment: @assylias it is the line in the original question with the static int, and afaik there shouldn't be anything modifying it.

Comment: Did you even post the correct source file? In the compiler message, it looks like the code line says `timeOfInactivity = 1000 * 60 * 9;`, but in the posted code snippet, it says `timeOfInactivity = 540000;`. Maybe you are compiling a different version than you think? Even so, the compilation error message still sounds strange though...

Comment: @Alderath sorry...that was an attempt to fix it :$

Comment: That makes little sense... If it were in an IDE I would say: try to clean and build.

Comment: Please post more code...

Comment: Check your imports for entries outside of the java namespace... But obviously you're not posting enough code.

Comment: sorry for the long answer time, I had to clear it upwards since it is proprietary ;) The source for the file can be seen here (for the next day): http://pastebin.com/t2M5mgd0

Comment: @Albatros: Don't use pastebin since it is blocked by most of the corporate websites. Paste your code in your original post.

Comment: @Albatros You can look at [import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder got error in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549464/import-sun-misc-base64encoder-got-error-in-eclipse) post. May be your issue is identical

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suppress javac warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855700/suppress-javac-warning)

Comment: I think the file is too large to include directly, I'll just try some more drastic experiments on the file and see if that removes the error, and if not I might have a shorter file to paste here ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution found I removed all all imports in the file, and replaced everything with stubs.

That made java report the error in another file.

The other file had a bad and unused import (import com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.NEW).

So I'll recommend anyone getting this error to search your entire workspace for NEW

Comment: The recommendation is to check for unused imports after each change of the source-code. Those NEW is probably the result of a misused quickfix of an IDE.

Comment: yea, personally I use the eclipse save actions to clean up unused imports and reformat edited lines, but not everyone on the team does that ;)

Comment: More generally, the error about "internal proprietary API" refers to the use of classes in the `com.sun.*` packages.  You should never use any `com.sun.*` classes in your programs.