# How can I resolve the following Java error?

Tags: java

I'm trying to use Parallel for loops from https://github.com/tantaman/commons. After importing the code to Eclipse, I get the error from the following function

```
public static String asURLSafeBase64String(UUID uuid) {
    try {
        return URLEncoder.encode(Base64Utils.trim(new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(UUIDUtils.asByteArray(uuid))), "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "";
}
```

with the following error

> Access restriction: The method 'CharacterEncoder.encode(byte[])' is not API (restriction on required library 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\lib\rt.jar')

I'm using Java 8 by the way. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Seems like you dont have access to your Java folder on your Windows. If you cannot amend the access, try installing JDK into different location.

Comment: possible duppicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549464/import-sun-misc-base64encoder-got-error-in-eclipse

Comment: i am guessing they finally removed that encoder (it's been considered deprecated for several versions).  iirc, java 8 introduced an "official" base64 encoder/decoder, you should be using that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched back to Java version 7 solved the problem.