# Maven repository with sun.misc.BASE64Decoder

Tags: maven, maven-repository

Is there a working Maven repository with `sun.misc.BASE64Decoder`?

Have looked and could not find any that works, this should be it https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/sun.misc/BASE64Decoder/unknown but it's broken.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder results in error compiled in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549464/import-sun-misc-base64encoder-results-in-error-compiled-in-eclipse)

Comment: Please check https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html